# Facebook like change admin for your page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I inserted a like button for one of my page and tested it, while doing it I used a dummy account of facebook for testing but something went wrong cause the admin rights for the page is now linked to the dummy account and now I need to transfer the ownership to one of my app to track the likes and shares. Well I just follow the standard creation of like button and I think something went wrong because I use the dummy app ID then liked my page. Now the problem is the one that can track the insight for my page is the dummy account and not my app. How can I solve this one?

Another thing is that is it possible to transfer the page administration to my app or it should really be my own account ID that I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page administration should be done by a personal account.   You can have multiple users administrating a page so in case one person leaves facebook, another is ready to take their place.  I'm not even sure an app can become a page admin.

Comment: I've already deleted the page that was created in my dummy account and I think it just takes a lot of time before it was rendered properly. Anyway, I just wonder what is the use of the <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID" />?
is it the one that needed to set the admin for your page?

Comment: That's one place.  There's also another, you need to go into your facebook page, click [edit page] (on the far right) then on the left column nav, click Manage admins. Ensure you have the appropriate people listed there.